# Why isn't MATLAB's filter function commutative?

Tags: matlab, math

I'm trying to use [MATLAB's filter function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) and noticed that switching b and x (with a = 1) give me different results.

I'm confused as to why this is happening. The filter can be represented as a convolution, and convolution is commutative so assuming a is 1, I would expect the same output if b and x are switched. In other words, using an input signal X with filter B should produce the same output as using an input signal B with a filter X since X * B = B * X where the star denotes convolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` does not apply a convolution with kernel B. Input parameter `b` defines the coefficients of the polynomial that describes the filter.

You are looking for the function [conv](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html).

--

EDIT:

My bad, you are right, switching `b` and `x` should give the same results. And for me it does:

```
>> x=rand(1,10);
>> y=rand(1,10);
>> filter(b,1,x)
ans =
    0.1713    0.6816    0.9775    1.4413    1.1430    1.2836    1.5635    1.8397    2.3768    1.7775
>> filter(x,1,b)
ans =
    0.1713    0.6816    0.9775    1.4413    1.1430    1.2836    1.5635    1.8397    2.3768    1.7775
```

`filter` always returns a result of length of `x`, so if `b` is shorter than `x`, and you switch them, you'll get a shorter result back.

Comment: If the denominator is one, the coefficients of the numerator of the polynomial that describes the filter is equivalent to the impulse response.

Comment: You're right. But it's a feed forward filter, I'll update my answer a bit.